# When I type the letter f in VSCode Vim, it deletes the text

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I installed the `vim` extension in `vscode`. I pressed `i` to enter in `insert` mode.
I can type all the letters except `f`. It deletes the text. Is it supposed that `d` deletes the text, not `f`?
Is this a bug or am I in the wrong vim mode?
I use `i` for `insert` mode and `Ctrl + [` for returning to normal mode.

I searched for how to remap `vim` shortcuts to change the function of the letter `f`. I pressed `Ctrl+Shift+P` then opened Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON) but I did not find any vim shortcuts. I looked through the sortcuts list in the vscode `vim marketplace` but couldn't find a shortcut for the letter `f`. How can I change the letter `f` from deleting the text? I can not even write the letter f.

Edit: After searching, I found that I had messed up with the shortcuts in the keybindings.json without noticing.
this shortcut that cause me the problem:

```
{
        "key": "f f",
        "command": "editor.action.deleteLines",
        "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
 },
```

I don't know how I didn't notice that. I was focused on the vim's shortcuts, just typing Vim in the search, and looking for the shortcut that deletes the line. And in the end it wasn't in Vim shortcuts at all. I just deleted this shortcut and it works fine.

Comment: `f` doesn't delete, it's "find". In normal mode you press `f` then a character, and the cursor jumps to that character on your line. If `f` is deleting text in insert mode (or normal mode) then something else is wrong. You shouldn't need to remap anything.

Comment: yes f used to find characters but in my case it deletes texts. I uninstalled the vim extension and installed it again but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Hard to tell as you may be the only person in the world encountering this behavior. Are you on Ubuntu/Linux/using a weird keyboard, something wrong with your hardware/firmware? Or other apps you have installed that hijack keypresses? I would also try disabling other vscode plugins to see if there's a conflict.

Comment: Unfortunately, I messed up with the shortcuts in the keybindings.json           {
        "key": "f f",
        "command": "editor.action.deleteLines",
        "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
 },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this shortcut without noticing. I made the letter `f` delete the lines.

```
{
        "key": "f f",
        "command": "editor.action.deleteLines",
        "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
 },
```

Just delete this shortcut or change it to another key.

I think why I made this mistake is because when I went to preferences > keyboard shortcuts > then I typed vim in the search bar to see which shortcut deleted the line and ended up only checking vim shortcuts. But when I searched for the letter f, I found it was not in the list of vim shortcuts.